# Gaussian fit to discrete values

Tags: distribution, gaussian

I'm new in C++ and really I'm struggling with this. 
I have a matrix with discrete values that adapt Gaussian distribution. I need an algorithm in C++ to define the parameters of the Gaussian fit. Any suggestions or any help?? 
This is one of the vectors in my data set {14, 3, 2, 83, 263, 236, 101, 27, 7, 13, 12, 8} the increment is 2 ns between each value.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bathsheba already said, all that's needed to characterize the Gaussian (a.k.a. normal) distribution is the mean and variance.  You can estimate these with the [sample mean and sample variance s^2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_variance#Population_variance_and_sample_variance) of your data, respectively.

However, you ***shouldn't do so***!  A histogram and normal quantile plot of your data show that they look nothing like the Gaussian distribution.  Gaussians should have a histogram which is bell-shaped and symmetric.  Your data, despite the small sample size, are so skewed that even the exponential distribution doesn't look like a particularly good fit.  In the Normal Quantile Plot, if your data were Gaussian the points would fall along a relatively straight line (the red line is the best fit straight line for your values) and well within the dotted-line boundaries.  Your data aren't even vaguely close to being a good fit for the normal distribution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute the first two moments - mean and variance - from your sample.

That will give you parameters of the normal distribution.